# Invert displacement movement controlled by null?

Tags: node-editor, displacement

I animated the displacement of a sphere using an empty (upwards). I mixed it with another but I'd need that second one to move downwards. I want to invert that empty movement somehow using nodes to get it but no luck. Can you help me? Thanks[image]

Comment: You could invert the color after the voronoi texture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a *Vector Math* node set to *Multiply* by (-1, -1, -1) to get the opposite of the input Vector. You can also use a mapping node to do the same thing with the *Scale* fields.

Also, FYI semantically, the *inverse* and the *opposite* are not the same thing.

[image]

[image]